How to change partition size when building an AOSP target
I am trying to build an emulator from AOSP branch android-14.0.0_r45, and the target product is sdk_tablet_arm64-userdebug. This is not shown in lunch menu, but I can still use it in lunch and build an emulator running with the Android emulator, it boots up as an Android 14 tablet fine.
The "super partition size" of emulated device has only 1.5 GB, so I want to increase it to 4GB. Here is what I did to change it: in the device/generic/goldfish/64bitonly/product/sdk_tablet_arm64.mk, I changed the following two lines:
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_SIZE := 4294967296  # <--- Changed from 1619001344
BOARD_EMULATOR_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS_SIZE := 4286578688 # <---- Changed from 1610612736

The modified target is built and runing OK, so I thought I "successfully" changed the partition size from 1.5 GB to 4 GB, until I ran adb remount and saw such errors:
[liblp] Device size does not match (got 1619001344, expected 4294967296)
[liblp] Block device super size mismatch (expected4294967296, got 1619001344)

I think somewhere (kernel?) it is still configured as 1.5 GB instead of 4 GB, but not sure where exactly it is. Thanks
I searched the number 1619001344 in the whole AOSP, but I only found relevant entries in sdk_tablet_arm64.mk, so I guess there might be other place dictating this size?
